# squaring an int and showing the last digit - upgrade for a code

Tags: string, loops, char, atoi

Could anyone help me to upgrade my code ? 
I bet the function could be done in shorter and more elegant way, could you show me the proper direction or examples how to write that?
Thanks for the replies, here's the code ( written in Codeblocks 16.01):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int D,a,b,bb,liczba,dlugosc;
int main()
{
    cout << "liczba testow: ";
    cin >> D;
    while(D<11 && D>0){
        for (int j=0;j<D;j++){
            cin >> a >> b;
            if(a<0 | a>1000000000 | b<0 | b>1000000000){
                break;
            }
            liczba =a;
            for(int i=1;i<b;i++){
               liczba = liczba*a;
            }
            char aa[10] = {0};
            itoa(liczba,aa,10);
            string bb = aa;

            int dlugosc = bb.length();

            cout << bb << endl;
            cout << bb[dlugosc-1] << endl;
            a = 0;


        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "upgrade your code"

Comment: Shorter is not always better. Do you want faster code? Code following best practices? etc.

Comment: I would like get any info if i could reduce maybe an amount of loops or do same thing but in cleverer way.  I'm also sure, that conversion between int and string could be done without using char. PS  "liczba testow: " stands for "amount of tests:"